# Cisco Static NAT with DHCP outside interface

Tags: dhcp, cisco-ios-12, snat

I'm working on a Cisco 2800, trying to get it to NAT an internal RFC1918 to a WAN. The WAN (ISP) address is from DHCP. I've never worked with NAT on a Cisco before. Cisco's tech pages are also listing some commands that don't exist in the 2800. Please see `sh run` output below. Hopefully, someone sees what I'm leaving out. I can ping from each interface to its' connected network, but cannot cross the router.

=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.11.27 21:00:50 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=

```
Cisco_Edge#sh run  
Building configuration...  

Current configuration : 2888 bytes 
!
version 12.4  
no service pad  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
service password-encryption  
!  
hostname Cisco_Edge  
!  
boot-start-marker  
boot-end-marker  
!  
no aaa new-model  
!  
resource policy  
!  
mmi polling-interval 60  
no mmi auto-configure  
no mmi pvc  
mmi snmp-timeout 180  
ip subnet-zero  
ip cef  
!  
ip domain name [redacted]  
ip ssh version 2  
!  
crypto pki certificate chain   
  [redacted]  
!  
interface FastEthernet0/0  
 description WAN - Outside - Untrusted  
 ip dhcp client client-id FastEthernet0/0  
 ip dhcp client class-id Cisco  
 ip dhcp client hostname Cisco-Edge  
 ip dhcp client lease 3 0 0  
 ip address dhcp  
 ip nat outside  
 ip nat enable  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 duplex auto  
 speed auto  
!  
interface FastEthernet0/1  
 description LAN - Inside - Trusted  
 ip address 172.16.16.1 255.255.255.0  
 ip nat inside  
 ip nat enable  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 speed auto  
 full-duplex  
 no mop enabled  
!  
ip classless  
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp  
!  
!  
no ip http server  
no ip http secure-server  
!  
control-plane  
!  
line con 0  
line aux 0  
line vty 0 4  
 login local  
!  
end  

Cisco_Edge#  sh ip int bri  
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            10.0.1.245      YES DHCP   up                    up        
FastEthernet0/1            172.16.16.1     YES manual up                    up        
NVI0                       unassigned      YES unset  up                    up        
Cisco_Edge#sh ip route  
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 10.0.1.1 to network 0.0.0.0  

    172.16.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets  
C       172.16.16.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1  
     10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets  
C       10.0.1.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0  
S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 10.0.1.1  
Cisco_Edge#ping 10.0.1.1  

Type escape sequence to abort.  
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.0.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:  
!!!!!  
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/4 ms  
Cisco_Edge#ping 10.0.1.1 source fa0/1  

Type escape sequence to abort.  
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.0.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:  
Packet sent with a source address of 172.16.16.1   
.....  
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)  
Cisco_Edge#exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I ***strongly*** urge you to have a firewall in from of your router, and you could do the NAT on that. You have the interfaces described as "Trusted" and "Untrusted", but those are firewall terms. Without a firewall, nothing should be considered trusted.

If you are willing to risk your network with no firewall, something like this should work (you don't specify the IOS version, so you may need to make accommodations for differences in commands):

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description WAN - Outside
 ip address dhcp
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
 no shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description LAN - Inside
 ip address 172.16.16.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 no shutdown
!  
ip nat inside source list 10 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 172.16.16.1 0.0.0.255
!
```

Comment: Ron, the original plan was to place my ASA out front, but I have been told by multiple people not to use the firewall for layer 3, hence the router at the edge. The plan was to drop the firewall behind the router. I know those are firewall terms, and I do understand the difference...I guess I was just trying to make it clear for me.  

let me plug in this config and I'll see where it gets me. IOS is 12.4 by the way.

Comment: The traffic needs to travel through the firewall, anyway, and it is better to have it in front of everything. It can do the NAT, and your router can do the LAN routing. If you expose your router to the public Internet without at least a software router on it, you are risking everything. You would need the ISO security version to have the firewall on the router.